# Trying to create a matrix (nested list) using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I am trying to make a matrix that is basically a nested list using a dictionary I made from information in a given file.

[image]

This is the matrix that I am trying to accomplish, note that I don't want it to look exactly like it, but to be a nested list and no need to even return/print it since I need it for something else
 This is what the dictionary looks like

```
{1: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '002', 'Cost': '0100.00', 'Time': '04.00'},
2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '003', 'Cost': '0500.00', 'Time': '01.50'}, 
3: {'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'}, 
4: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0700.00', 'Time': '10.00'}, 
5: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0550.00', 'Time': '06.75'}, 
6: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0750.00', 'Time': '10.50'}, 
7: {'Origin': '005', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0460.00', 'Time': '08.00'}, 
8: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1500.00', 'Time': '05.75'}}
```

and this is the part where I need help

```
first_list=[]                   
second_list=[]
for c in range(1,count):            
    first_list.append(main_dict[c]['Origin'])   #puts all origins in one list
    second_list.append(main_dict[c]['Destination']) #puts all destinations iin one list
locations=[]
locations.extend(first_list)
locations.extend(second_list)
locations=(list(set(locations))) #gets rid of any duplicates
locations.sort()



mat_nxn = [[0 for x in range(len(locations))] for y in range(len(locations))] #in this section the main matrix is created 
for i in range(len(locations)):
    mat_nxn[0][i]=locations[i] #fills the first row with the locations
    mat_nxn[i][0]=locations[i] #fills the first column with the locations
for i in range(1,count-1):
    column=main_dict[i]['Origin']
    line=main_dict[i]['Destination']
```

what the code is supposed to do when complete is fill the matrix with tuple of Origin/Destination as the given picture states
everything runs fine by far but now I can't continue because I don't seem to be able to fill the matrix as the given dictionary, keep in mind the input of the dictionary might differ from file to file!
Is there like a

Comment: It is not at all clear how the tuple in your sample matrix comes from the data in your sample dictionary. Please explain in words the meaning of the matrix data in relation to the dictionary.

Comment: The first line is the "departure code" Orgirin the first column is the "where it is headed" the Destination now if there is a connection between the origin and the location " in the same dictionary they are origin and destination" it means I am going from origin *first line in matrix* to destination *first column* and if this "trip" exists I want it to show the tuple *pretty much a given dictionary* of it and if it does not then the matrix will show None

Comment: That description you gave does not give your sample matrix from your sample dictionary. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).